# Can I pass values to non-APEX static files?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

Using APEX 18.2. I am listening to IG's grid model to set a net amount item of an invoice when specific changes happen to the model, using the following code:

```
(function($) {

 $(function() {
/*gRegionStaticId is the variable hodlds the IG that owns the model. */
  $(gRegionStaticId).on("interactivegridviewmodelcreate", function(event, ui) {
   var sid,
    model = ui.model;
   console.log('modelCreated');
   if (ui.viewId === "grid") {
    sid = model.subscribe({
     onChange: function(type, change) {
      if (type !== "set" && type !== "move" && type !== "metaChange" && type !== "insert" && type !== "clearChanges") {
  /*"pFlowStepId" is page's number. gSetNetAmount is the global variable holds the function to set net amount.*/
$s("P" + $v('pFlowStepId') + "_NET_AMOUNT", gSetNetAmount().toString());
          //alert('&APP_PAGE_ID');
      }
     }
    });
   }
  });
 });

})(apex.jQuery);
```

The code is stored in a static file that's called from the `File URLs` page attribute. gRegionStaticId and gSetNetMaount are global variables defined and assigned the static id of the IG that owns the model I am listening to and the function that calculates the net amount respectively at `Function and global variables` page attribute . I am doing so to use the code dynamically instead of duplicating it in multiple pages.
The problem(I think) is that `File URL` attribute that loads the static file with the above code runs before setting the global variables at `Function and global variables` page attribute.

Is there a way to set the variables before the static file loaded? Or maybe pass values to the static files?

Comment: Hi Eslam, 
Any reason why you can't add the code in the same static file?
Can you share the code you have in Function and global variables?

Comment: I want to use the code dynamically because I am going to use it in multiple pages. So, I can not hard code regions' static id's or the functions' names that calculates the net amount.
There is nothing in the "Function and global variables declaration" attribute in any page except, 
var gRegionStaticId;
var gSetNetAmount; // to hold the function that calculate the net amount.

Comment: and the definition of the functions needed:
`function getGrid(pRgName){ 
return apex.region(pRgName).widget().interactiveGrid('getViews','grid');} 
function itemTotal(){
var pr_dtl_model = getGrid("PR_DTL").model;
var vSumTotal = 0;
pr_dtl_model.forEach( function( record, index, id ) {
var v_total = Number(pr_dtl_model.getValue( record, "TOTAL" )), 
meta = pr_dtl_model.getRecordMetadata( id ); 
if (!meta.deleted) {vSumTotal = vSumTotal + v_total; } }); 
return vSumTotal; }`

Comment: After giving it a little bit of thought, I think I could solve the problem of passing the IG's static id. And that would be through assigning every IG involved in every page a specific class i.e `igWithModelToListTo` and change the corresponding part in the static file 
`$(.igWithModelToListTo)` instead of `$(#gRegionStaticId)` but still the part of passing the function not solved.

Comment: @SalimHlayel I posted the answer below but I think it's a bad practice to make the whole code dynamic because then the function that calculates the net amount - `itemTotal()` would be mutable and can be manipulated through the browser's tools. Am I right? Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I gave the region a css class and referred it in the static file as I mentioned above and regarding the net amount calculation function.

I assigned the variable gSetNetAmount the function name `gSetNetAmount = itemTotal;` in `Execute when page loads` page attribute after declaring the variable in `Function and global variables declaration` page attribute. And it worked very well. Thanks @Salim.